# Website tries downloading index.php instead of loading it only on one machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, browser

For a few weeks I've had a problem on my PC (running Windows 7) with one login page related to my university - the site works just fine as long as you're not logged in but if you try to (i.e. put in your credentials and click "log in") the browser prompts me to download index.php as if I was going to download a regular file as opposed to loading the logged-in website.

How can I fix this? It does the same thing on every browser on my PC (tried Firefox, Chrome and Safari), clearing cache does nothing, neither do restarts. On the other hand, it works just fine on my Android phone, iPad and laptop. It also works OK for my friends.

I would guess the server configuration may be the problem but still, isn't there a way to let the browser know what it should do? On the other hand, it should not work on other's PCs if it were really only the server's problem. What can I do?

Comment: Do you have a file association set for `.php` files?

Comment: @DavidPostill - right now, Adobe Dreamweaver is set as my `.php` default

Comment: Try removing that association and see what happens - it maybe downloading the file because it thinks you want to edit it.

Comment: This tells me that the webserver is not executing the php file as a web page, but instead as a static document. A webserver implements Handlers and Modules that determine what to do when a file is requested. It sounds like the handlers for GET for .php files is not being handled by a runtime module that understands PHP, so it tries to present the file itself to the requestor. I'd guess that logging in is interfering with your pathing, and the place the file is served from after login is not being interpreted. This is definitely a server config issue.

Comment: This indicates a server configuration not a client configuration problem.  You cannot fix this problem as the end user, it must be solved, by the Administrator of the server.

Comment: @FrankThomas If that was the case it would be broken for everybody.

Comment: @Ramhound If that was the case it would be broken for everybody.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I would argue that browsers behave differently.  I know Safari attempts to tell me that a executable is assoicated with TeamViewer by mistake on my iPhone.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but the OP said in the question " it works just fine on my Android phone, iPad and laptop. It also works OK for my friends" - that *may* indicate a broken server, but more likely a broken client.

Comment: @Straightfw - What browser are you using and what is the website?  *It will be easy enough to test if its a server configuration problem, if it is, then any attempt to login will cause this problem (in theory)* since the php is doing account authentication.

Comment: @DavidPostill - it seems to have solved the problem! Thank you very much, if you add the comment as an answer I'll happily accept it :)

And to address the other replies - as DavidPostill correctly stressed, it works on a multitude of configs of my friends and even on all other of my own so it seemed very very likely at least a part of the fault was on my PC's side.

Comment: @Straightfw Answer added :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Browser downloads index.php instead of loading it in the browser

This can be caused by a misconfigured server, but in this specific case this is unlikely as:

> it works just fine on my Android phone, iPad and laptop. It also works OK for my friends.

It can also be caused by having a file association set for `.php` that has an action that requires downloading the file.

For example, if `.php` is associated with an editor (Dreamweaver in your case) then `index.php` will be downloaded and opened with the associated program so it can be edited.

In case you need to restore it again later, use the following command to see the current association before you remove it:

```
assoc .php
```

Then, to remove the association run the following command:

```
assoc .php=
```

Removing the association will resolve the issue.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [assoc](http://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html) - Display or change the association between a file extension and a fileType

Comment: Somehow, this doesn't make sense. Notepad++ is my editor for HTML files, but when I open an HTML file online, it doesn't try to download it...

Comment: @InterLinked Notepad++ is weird when it comes to registered file extension. I believe it will if you have **Always Use This Program To Open This File** option turned on.

Comment: Nope, just tried that, it still works normal for me

Comment: @InterLinked OK. Will look at it more closely later, but in the meantime it resolves the OP's issue.

Comment: What does OP stand for? I keep seeing this all over this site

Comment: @InterLinked **O**riginal **P**oster :) - the person who asked the question.

Comment: Oh heck, it seems like my joy may have been premature :( Yesterday after doing what you proposed everything worked fine for the test logins that I performed but today it prompts me to download index.php again :( Do you have any other ideas I may try?

Comment: @Straightfw Not at the moment. I'll try to come back to this later ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - Great, let me know if you come across some idea :)

Comment: @Straightfw Unfortunately I can't repro the problem.